# maxscale proxy does not route read requests from flask-sqlachamy to the slaves

Tags: mysql, flask-sqlalchemy, maxscale

I have a maxscale mariadb cluster with one master and two slaves. I am using flask-sqlachemy ORM for querying and writing.

I have written read queries in style

`db.session(User).join()....`

Now all my read queries are going to max scale master node

Below are maxcalse logs

```
2021-09-14 17:38:26   info   : (1239) (Read-Write-Service) > Autocommit: [disabled], trx is [open], cmd: (0x03) COM_QUERY, plen: 287, type: QUERY_TYPE_READ, stmt: SELECT some_col FROM user 
2021-09-14 17:38:26   info   : (1239) [readwritesplit] (Read-Write-Service) Route query to master: Primary <
```

I have tried other ways too

```
conn = mysql_connector.connect(...)
conn.autocommit(True)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
```

This works fine and routes query to one of slave.

But my most of code is written in ORM style. Is there any way to achieve this while using `flask-sqlalchemy`

Answer (score 0):

If autocommit is disabled, you always have an open transaction: use `START TRANSACTION READ ONLY` to start an explicit read-only transaction. This allows MaxScale to route the transaction to a slave.

Comment: How can I use that in flask-sqlalchemy?

Comment: There's an open issue for sqlalchemy to support this: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5815 Currently this doesn't seem to be possibly unless you execute an explicit SQL query whenever you want to start a transaction.